# d3 Stacked Bar Chart - Bars not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

d3 stacked bar chart first attempt using an example [here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-create-stacked-bar-chart-using-d3).

The only parts I have changed, except for the legend section, is the JSON in `var data` and this section to match the data:

```
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["alex", "mindy", "sean", "karen"].map(function(fruit) {
      return data.map(function(d) {
        return {x: d3.time.format("%Y").parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
      });
    }));
```

Chart is rendering horizontal lines, but no bars or axis.  See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh1eo5vr/)

```
// set the dimensions of the canvas
var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 90},
    width = 845 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 540 - margin.top - margin.bottom;  


var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    
var data = [
    {"Category":"Knowledge","Year 1":3,"Year 2":0,"Year 3":2},
    {"Category":"Comprehension","Year 1":14,"Year 2":1,"Year 3":0},
    {"Category":"Application","Year 1":5,"Year 2":13,"Year 3":19},
    {"Category":"Analysis","Year 1":5,"Year 2":2,"Year 3":1},
    {"Category":"Synthesis","Year 1":2,"Year 2":1,"Year 3":5},
    {"Category":"Evaluation","Year 1":6,"Year 2":22,"Year 3":0}
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3"].map(function(years) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.Category), y: +d[years]};
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } );

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });
 
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});
 
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Year 1";
      case 1: return "Year 2";
      case 2: return "Year 3";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");
    
tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you used had x-axis values which were calendar years which were parsed with `d3.time.format()`. As you are using text (non-calendar) values you needed to adjust the code to remove the date parsing and formatting for axis labels.

Removing this and adding space to the right margin for the legend seems to give you what you were aiming for.

```js
// set the dimensions of the canvas
var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 90, // add space for legend
    bottom: 70,
    left: 90
  },
  width = 845 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 540 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var data = [{
    "Category": "Knowledge",
    "Year 1": 3,
    "Year 2": 0,
    "Year 3": 2
  },
  {
    "Category": "Comprehension",
    "Year 1": 14,
    "Year 2": 1,
    "Year 3": 0
  },
  {
    "Category": "Application",
    "Year 1": 5,
    "Year 2": 13,
    "Year 3": 19
  },
  {
    "Category": "Analysis",
    "Year 1": 5,
    "Year 2": 2,
    "Year 3": 1
  },
  {
    "Category": "Synthesis",
    "Year 1": 2,
    "Year 2": 1,
    "Year 3": 5
  },
  {
    "Category": "Evaluation",
    "Year 1": 6,
    "Year 2": 22,
    "Year 3": 0
  }
];

// not required
// var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3"].map(function(years) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      // this is not a calendar date - do not parse it as one
      // x: parse(d.Category) 
      x: d.Category,
      y: d[years]
    };
  });
}));

// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width - 10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
      return d.y0 + d.y;
    });
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447"]//, "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d
  });

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  // not using calendar dates
  //.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")")
  .call(xAxis)


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", null);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", "none");
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors.slice().reverse()[i];
  });

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        return "Year 1";
      case 1:
        return "Year 2";
      case 2:
        return "Year 3";
    }
  });

// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

path.domain {
  stroke: none;
}

.y .tick line {
  stroke: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='chart'></div>
```